# How to style a especific part of an array in a div in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

so I have an array in a div with `opacity = "0.5"` and I want to find a certain spot of that div to style with `opacity = "1"`.

I would find that spot if it was equal to a variable dummy.

This event will happen more than once.

And this is what I got:

```
   <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var word = "" //word variable
        var wLength = 0 //word length variable
        var dummy = "" //letter guessed
        var dm = new Array(26)



        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input.in2").hide()
        })

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input.bi2").hide()
        })

        function doGetWord(){
            word = F.gword.value;
            wLength = word.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
                document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "
            }
            $("input.wordi").hide()
            $("input.bi").hide()
            $("input.in2").show()
            $("input.bi2").show()
        }

        function doGuess(){
            dummy = F.t.value
            if(dummy.length > 1){
                dummy = ""
                F.t.value = ""
            }
            else{
                F.t.value = ""
                dd = dummy.toString()
                window["cl" + dd]
                if(window["cl" + dd] == false){
                    alert("Letter already used, please try again with another letter")
                    dummy = ""
                    F.t.value = ""
                }
                else{
                    window["cl" + dd] = false
                    F.t.value = ""

                    let dc = document.getElementById("chrts");

        // initialize children
   let alp = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
    "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
    dc.innerHTML = alp.map(function(ltr) { return "<span>" + ltr + "
   </span>"; }).join('');
      Array.from(dc.children).forEach(function(letterSpan) { 
         letterSpan.style.opacity = "0.5"; })
   // declare opacity-changing function
 function changeOpacityOfLetter(dummy) {
 const letters = dc.children;
  for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
 let letterSpan = letters[i];
    if (dummy === letterSpan.innerText) {
    letterSpan.style.opacity = "1";
}
}
}
changeOpacityOfLetter(dummy);
                    doGuessWord();
                }
            }
        }



        function doGuessWord(){
            const letters = document.getElementById("dword").textContent.split(' ');
                for(i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
                    if(dummy === word.charAt(i)) {
                        letters[i] = dummy;
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("dword").textContent = letters.join(' ');

        }
    </script>
```

The var `dummy`, could be up from a to z.
I could use jquery if it's easier for you.

Comment: First off you can't "find a certain spot of that div to style ". Style applies to the entire element. So with the code you have, what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: What @gforce301 said. And if you want to style some particular part, you'd have to create inner elements, such as `<div><span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>...</div>` and style those `span`s.

Comment: What do you recommend then?

Comment: What's the easiest and quickest way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply the `opacity` on the parent `div` and override it in the children. The children opacity is a function of the opacity of the parent.

In other words, if you use `style="opacity: 0.5;"` on a parent and `style="opacity: 1;"` on a child, the end result is the child with `0.5` opacity still -- [the child will have 100% (`1`) of 50% (`0.5`) opacity](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/c8pfez6t/)).

So, you have to apply the opacity on each child, setting `style="opacity: 0.5;"` on some and `style="opacity: 1;"` on the other:

```js
//
// RUN JUST ONCE
// 
let dc = document.getElementById("chrts");

// initialize children
let alp = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
dc.innerHTML = alp.map(function(ltr) { return "<span>" + ltr + "</span>"; }).join('');
Array.from(dc.children).forEach(function(letterSpan) { letterSpan.style.opacity = "0.5"; })

// declare opacity-changing function
function changeOpacityOfLetter(letter) {
  const letters = dc.children;
  for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    let letterSpan = letters[i];
    if (letter === letterSpan.innerText) {
      letterSpan.style.opacity = "1";
    }
  }
}

//
// RUN EVERYTIME THE USER INPUTS
//
changeOpacityOfLetter("g");
let dummy = "w"; // example using variable
changeOpacityOfLetter(dummy);
```

```css
div { font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<div id="chrts"></div>
```

Comment: that's awesome man, but if i put another dummy there , the other one who had full opacity, goes back to 0.5, which should not happen, what should I change then?

Comment: I separated the initialization of the opacity of the children from the modification of the `dummy` one. Check the answer. Btw, in what browsers are you gonna execute this code?

Comment: I'm gonna execute it in chrome for now, but is there a downside for other browsers?

Comment: @ThecheesiestChannel Depending on the browser, `let` of `let variableName` is not available. Also `Array.from()` or `.map` in `alp.map()` are only available in newer browsers. (It wouldn't run on IE9, for instance.)

Comment: hmm okay, but if I change the dummy variable the first one still disappears :/.

Comment: I think what you want is a function. Check the update to the answer.

Comment: It still does not work, like for example, the variable dummy is obtained thorugh user input and changes everytime the user types one more letter, so each time it would change the opacity to 1 while the previous one staying 1 too and all the others 0.5.

Comment: You shouldn't run the whole code every time the user inputs. Only execute the second part. See the updated answer.

Comment: Where should I put the code to run just once? All this code was in a function btw

Comment: It really depends on your whole code. Probably place it in a `<script>`, right by the place you declare this function you say this code was in.

Comment: Sure, gimme a minute.

Comment: Here, the best I got: http://jsbin.com/mejunixeje/edit?html,output I added `//////` around code I changed. Provided you add what is missing, it should work, or at least be closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Surround each letter with a span, then you can do what you wish:

```
let alp = ["<span>a</span>","<span>b</span>",...];
```

Then you will need to update the subsequent lines of code to grab each span. Something like this:

```
let dc = document.getElementById("chrts").childNodes;
dc.forEach(e => {
  if (e.textContent === dummy) {
    e.style.opacity = "1";
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I be able to compare my variable dummy that way?